# find solution of the PDE: $u_x+2(y-1)u_y=\frac 52f(x)(y-1)u$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

the PDE is:

$u_x+2(y-1)u_y=\frac 52f(x)(y-1)u$ using the transformation $t=x$ and $n=\frac 12\ln(y-1)$,  I arrived to:
$W_t=\frac 52 W e^{2n+2t}f(t)$, and I don't know where to go from here (it seems that something is wrong). $f$ is a continuous function.

Comment: You should specify what is $W$.

Comment: W=W(t,n)=u(x(t,n),y(t,n))

Comment: Is your calculation somehow related to the method of characteristics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Making the change of variables

$$
\cases{
t = x\\
n = a x + b\ln(y-1)
}
$$

we obtain $u(x,y) = w(t,n)$ with

$$
(a+2 b) w_n\left(t,n\right)+w_t\left(t,n\right)=f(t) e^{\frac{n-a t}{b}} w\left(t,n\right)
$$

now choosing $a = -2b$ we have

$$
w_t\left(t,n\right)=f(t) e^{\frac{n+2b t}{b}} w\left(t,n\right)
$$

this PDE can be solved as a regular ODE giving

$$
w(t,n) = e^{e^{\frac nb}}\phi(n)e^{\int_0^t e^{2\xi}f(\xi)d\xi} = \psi(n)e^{\int_0^t e^{2\xi}f(\xi)d\xi}
$$